# Summation of all positive divisors

Tags: prolog

a query `sum(X,Y)` will answer the summation of all positive divisors of X (excluding X itself)
say, `sum(12,Y)` will answer `Y=16` because 1,2,3,4,6 are the divisors of 12.

i was going to implement the following prolog program but it failed, saying some variable was not instantiated.

```
sum(X,Y) :- f(X,Y,1).
f(X,Y,F) :- X>Y,X>F, 0 is X mod F, F1 is F+1, f(X,Y1,F1), Y is F+Y1.
f(X,Y,F) :- X>Y,X>F, not(0 is X mod F), F1 is F+1, f(X,Y,F1).
```

what's the problem of the above program?

thanks your help!

Comment: I think you need to use [clpfd](http://www.swi-prolog.org/man/clpfd.html) instead of raw arithmetic, because Prolog isn't smart enough out of the box to guess numbers in a range given these sorts of constraints.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not going to show you how to code a sum_of_divisors function, since it would not be very instructive. Instead, I can try to show you how to understand what went wrong with your `sum(12,Y)` query.

Let's see the error:

```
?- sum(12, Y).
ERROR: >/2: Arguments are not sufficiently instantiated
   Exception: (8) f(12, _G215, 1) ? a
% Execution Aborted
```

After you query

```
?- sum(12, Y).
```

The Prolog engine reads `sum(X,Y) :- f(X,Y,1).` and so it evaluates the second predicate:

```
f(X,Y,F)
```

where `X = 12`, `F = 1` and `Y` is not bound. So it tries this:

```
:- X>Y
```

which is

```
12 > _G350
```

where `_G350` is `Y`, a not instantiated variable.

The problem is that arithmetic predicates like `(>)/2` (and like `(+)/2` and `(*)/2`, etc..) require that **BOTH the variables you want to compare are instantiated**. You cannot query like this:

```
?- 12 > X
```

and expect the Prolog engine to find ALL the bindings to `X` such that `X` is less than 12. So you need to re-think your approach to the problem, and remember that you can do arithmetic only with NUMBERS, and not with numbers and variables.

Answer (score 2):

For full declarative arithmetic, you can use CLP(FD) as already suggested. For example, in SWI-Prolog, when I simply replace (is)/2 with (#=)/2 etc. to generalize the primitive arithmetic operations so that they also work with variables on both sides, I get:

```
:- use_module(library(clpfd)).

sum(X,Y) :- f(X,Y,1).

f(X,Y,F) :- X#>Y,X#>F, 0 #= X mod F, F1 #= F+1, f(X,Y1,F1), Y #= F+Y1.
f(X,Y,F) :- X#>Y,X#>F, 0 #\= X mod F, F1 #= F+1, f(X,Y,F1).
```

And now your sample query yields:

```
?- sum(12, Y).
false.
```

So clearly the program is too specific, check whether you forgot to describe an important case.